# ssh: "from" authorized host equivalent when using IPV6?

Tags: networking, ssh, dns, ipv6, amanda

I am running Amanda to backup a few local hosts, among them my laptop. For security reasons, the laptop is using [ssh as transport](https://wiki.zmanda.com/index.php/How_To:Set_up_transport_encryption_with_SSH) and there is a "from" option like this:

```
from="server.localdomain,server,192.168.2.xxx",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,command="/usr/lib/amanda/amandad -auth=ssh amdump"
```

IPv6 was already deployed in the LAN when I did that configuration but my router's DNS (dnsmasq) only replied with "A" records so that the ssh connection from the amanda server to the laptop went over IPV4 and all was fine.

I recently switched to Unbound as DNS server, which apparently tends to reply with IPV6 first: now the ssh key authentication is rejected because of the "from" line above. I have tried to add "UseDNS yes" to the client' sshd configuration file and restarting it, but it doesn't help, most likely because the reverse lookup still does not match the server hostname.

Since solving the reverse issue is non trivial (public & ULA prefixes plus temporary addresses), I thought of getting rid of the "from" option altogether: is there an equivalent (or better) level of security for ssh that does not rely on IP addresses and reverse lookups?

Comment: What threats are you concerned about? Someone copying the private key from your laptop to another host in the same LAN? Stealing the private key and connecting to your server from outside?

Comment: The amanda server is not accessible from outside the LAN, the main threat I am concerned about is unauthorized access to the laptop (amanda client) when I am traveling (theoretical question right now, I know!).

Comment: I ended up removing the "from" keyword and that's it. I'm leaving the question open on the odd chance somebody has a better idea.